# Plotting time series with different length

Tags: data-visualization

I have two time series (ts-variables) with different time length. It’s yearly data and they are stored as separate ts.objects. The first series starts in 1936 and the other starts in 1943 and both ends in 2012. Problem: I cannot find the R-script (commands) for plotting these series in one, single, nice figure which includes all observations.  Great if someone can help.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

If the data are on a comparable scale then you just need to set the x-axis limits to the range of the entire data, e.g.

```
set.seed(2) ## reproducible
dat1 <- data.frame(Year = seq(1936, 2012, by = 1), Y = runif(77))
dat2 <- data.frame(Year = seq(1943, 2012, by = 1), Y = runif(70))

ylim <- range(dat1$Y, dat2$Y)
xlim <- range(dat1$Year, dat2$Year)

plot(Y ~ Year, data = dat1, type = "l", col = "red", xlim = xlim,
     ylim = ylim)
lines(Y ~ Year, data = dat2, type = "l", col = "blue")
```

I'll leave you to prettify the plot.

Just noticed you said `ts` variables, so the following will work too

```
ts1 <- ts(runif(77), start = 1936, freq = 1)
ts2 <- ts(runif(70), start = 1943, freq = 1)

xlim <- c(1936, 2012)
ylim <- range(ts1, ts2)    

plot(ts1, ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim, col = "red")
lines(ts2, col = "blue")
```

With **your** data, replace `runif(n)` with the real data for the two time series.

Comment: Thank Gavin, but I have trouble with the scale of the y-axis (sorry about the mess): I applied your script in the following way: dat1 <- ts(TESTSKR.dat[,2], start =1936, freq = 1)  
dat2 <- ts(TESTLISTA.dat[,2], start =1943, freq = 1)
  set.seed(2) ## reproducible
dat1 <- data.frame(Year = seq(1936, 2012, by = 1), Y = runif(77))
dat2 <- data.frame(Year = seq(1943, 2012, by = 1), Y = runif(70))

ylim <- range(dat1$Y, dat2$Y)
xlim <- range(dat1$Year, dat2$Year)

plot(Y ~ Year, data = dat1, type = "l", col = "red", xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
lines(Y ~ Year, data = dat2, type = "l", col = "blue")

Comment: Gavin, the range of the y-axis is between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thank Gavin, still I have problem with the y-axis. It has a maximum of 1 and a minimum of 0. Both series are included. The variable are transformed to values between 0 and 1. The x-axis seems OK. As mentioned. I have two separate variables generated by the following R-script: SKR <- ts(TESTSKR.dat[,2], start =1936, freq = 1)  
AVERLI <- ts(TESTLISTA.dat[,2], start =1943, freq = 1). The problem is: How can I plot these variable in one, single figure.

Comment: That is because you are still using my dummy `Y` data. You are mixing the two examples. If you have `ts()` objects then you only need the example from the second chunk. I'll update.

Comment: Thank Gavin, your suggestion function perfectly!